# Comparing one element in a list of lists

Tags: java, list, for-loop, foreach

Thanks for taking the time to read.

So basically I have two "lists of lists", one for vertical lines and one for horizontal lines. Each of these "lists of lists" contains lists of Line2D elements (one list for each shape I'm dealing with). I want to compare each Line2D of every list to every other element in the other lists(for example: first element of first list in horizontal lines to every element in the OTHER lists of horizontal lines). If the two lines are closer than a certain value, something will occur.

I found some useful tips on here about how to compare one item in a list to all others, but how to do this for a list of lists escapes me. I have tried the code below and receive a Index Out of Bounds Exception Index: 3 Size: 3 Exception. I am a beginning coder so any and all advice is much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to provide more code or any other information. Thanks!

```
for(List<Line2D> list : horizontal) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for(int j =i+1; j < horizontal.get(j).size(); j++) {
            if((Math.abs(list.get(i).getY1()) - Math.abs(horizontal.get(j).get(i).getY1())) < 0.4) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, is this the best way to do this? I'm sure there is a more "elegant" way to compare these elements?

Comment: The elements of `List<Line2D>` are not lists, they are `Line2D` elements.  Do you have a code snippet which shows a list of lists?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `horizontal` is the 2D list

Comment: @4castle I see this, shame on me for asking that question.

Comment: If you happened to be using Java 8, there would be some *really* elegant ways to do this using a `Stream`, but it all depends on what `do something` is

Comment: @4castle the `do something` might be a bit outside of the scope of this question. I will be throwing an error method that is custom to the program I'm working on. Also, I believe I am using an older version of Java as this is an old program? Unsure how to check what version this program uses though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two outer `for` loops will touch on all unique pairs of `List<Line2D>` which can be taken from `horizontal`.  For each such two lists, the inner two `for` loops iterate over all possible combinations of entries, computing the absolute value of the differences in `Y1` values, and taking action if that difference should be less than a certain threshold.

```
for (int i=0; i < horizontal.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j < horizontal.size(); ++j) {
        List<Line2D> line1 = horizontal.get(i);
        List<Line2D> line2 = horizontal.get(j);

        for (int k=0; k < line1.size(); ++k) {
            for (int l=0; l < line2.size(); ++l) {
                if (Math.abs(line1.get(k).getY1() - line2.get(l).getY1()) < 0.4) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be interesting if someone can post a more elegant solution, possibly using Java 8 streams.

Comment: I believe `(Math.abs(line1.get(k).getY1()` needs to be `(Math.abs(line1.get(k).getY1())` to properly encapsulate the `Math.abs` function? Testing this now and will report back!

Comment: @ThorCodinson You are correct, I had a problem in there.  Actually, the `Math.abs()` should wrap the entire difference.  I copied from the OP which was using it wrongly.